# Planner Tasks Graph API: Update Task Issue

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

We have developed an application which calls [Update Task Planner Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannertask-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) to update task in Planner App. The API was working fine until some recent change in the MS docs and now it keeps throwing below error.

```
A type named 'microsoft.taskServices.plannerCheckListItemCollection' could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type.
```

Below is the code for creating and updating the Task using Graph API.

```
var newTask = new PlannerTask
{
    PlanId = "planID",
    BucketId = "bucketID",
    Title = "title"
};

Logger.LogInfo(userLogs + "Task object created, calling Graph API");
var taskResponse = await graphClient.Planner.Tasks.Request().AddAsync(newTask);

PlannerTaskDetails taskDetails = new PlannerTaskDetails
{
    Checklist = new PlannerChecklistItems { AdditionalData = checkListItems }
};

Logger.LogInfo(userLogs + "Getting Details of created Task");

PlannerTaskDetails getTaskDetails = await graphClient.Planner.Tasks[taskResponse.Id].Details.Request().GetAsync();
var eTagId = getTaskDetails.GetEtag();

Logger.LogInfo(userLogs + "Updating Task");
await graphClient.Planner.Tasks[taskResponse.Id].Details.Request()
    .Header("Prefer", "return=representation")
    .Header("If-Match", eTagId)
    .UpdateAsync(taskDetails);
```

Code snippet for **CheckListItems**:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> checkListItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();
checkListItems.Add(key, new PlannerChecklistItem
{
    Title = "title",
    IsChecked = True
});
```

Also proper App Permissions in Azure are already given as this was working fine till last month.

Comment: Outside of your code, can you repro the issue just with Graph Explorer or POSTMAN as well?

Comment: Can you try adding `ODataType = null`  while initializing the PlannerTaskDetails object? Had faced a similar issue with a different API in the SDK.

Comment: @Dev It is working fine with Postman and Graph Explorer. Facing issue in Graph SDK only.

Comment: Glad to hear that you isolated the issue. I would suggest you to [file the issue directly](https://github.com/microsoftgraph) at the respective language SDK build (at its Issues tab), so that it will be addressed.

Comment: @Neel Shah Thanks for your response. That did work as a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, and the issue should be resolved now.